# Ionic is not defined in Ionic v2 Push Notifications

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I was following this article: [Ionic Push Notification Guide](https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/)

But after doing all the steps I keep getting a "**Ionic is not defined**" in the next line of the `app.js` of my ionic application:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
  "debug": true
});
```

I dunno why this is happening, but this is my `angular.module.run` function complete for more insight in the matter:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });
    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);
    });
  });
})
```

Please, tell me any additional information I could provide to make this issue more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Just add below line after

```
<script src="lib/ionic/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

in your index.html file.

```
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.js"></script>
```

and use this comand: `ionic config set dev_push true`